# Angular16 how to create a Signal without initial value

Tags: typescript, angular-signals

I updated my Angular app to v16 and I'm trying to use Signals. Before, I was initializing my variables without initial value

```
filters: Filter[];
```

but as I'm using Signals it gives me an error.
`An argument for 'initialValue' was not provided`
Is there a way I can create a Signal without initializing its value?

I tried setting its Type to possibly null and giving it null value

```
signal<Category | null>(null);
```

But some other errors occurred in the file like
`Object is possibly 'null'.`

And I'm not a fan of using "any" type

So please can you provide another solution?

Comment: What about initializing with empty array?

Comment: I don't get what's the issue here, yes by defining a nullable value, you're to have to check for this !

Answer (score 7):

The signals have been designed with to specifically always have a synchronous value.

This means you have to explicitly create a signal with `null` or `undefined`.

For example:

```
const mySignal = new Signal<{value:number}|null>(null).
```

At the moment narrowing isn't working with signals in template. Expect an error when you do `{{ mySignal().value }}`.

You're going to have to rely on optional chaining operator (`.?`) : `{{ mySignal()?.value }}` to prevent that error.

The Angular team is aware of this issue and we can expect some improvements on that !

Answer (score 3):

How about defining it as a Partial?

```
signal<Partial<Category >>({});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is what @Akhil meant:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html